# 22.10 fans the coolers are working at full capacity

Tags: 22.10

After the update from 22.04, the only problem that haunts me is that the cooling system is running at full capacity. At the same time, the temperatures look like OK.

I tried to configure lm-sensors but it didn't solve my problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You many want to report this as a bug https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436753/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-10-the-fans-never-slow-down this user had the issue, and loading a kernel module for their motherboard caused it to work